# ¿Cómo obtener total dígitos de un numero en Java?

Tags: java

¿Cómo se puede obtener el total de dígitos que se compone un número entero en Java?

```
0    ==> 1 digito
1234 ==> 4 digitos
```

Comment: parece que lo que necesitas ya lo han preguntado antes XD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería algo así:

```
public class Ejemplo 
{ 
     public static void main(String args[]) 
     {
        System.out.println("El número " + 84 + " tiene " + Integer.toString(84).length() + " dígitos");
     }
}
```

Conviertes el número en un [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) y cuentas sus caracteres. Esta es la forma que entiendo **más clara** y **habitual**, pero luego tienes otras dos.

Un *segundo método* que **sacrifica la claridad frente a la eficiencia** usaría la clase [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) y sería éste:

```
digitos = (int)(Math.log10(numero)+1);
```

Eso si, sólo válido para números positivos.

Y un *tercer método* podría ser éste:

```
while(num !=0)
 {
   num = num/10;
   digitos++;
 }
```

Un código *menos claro*, pero si se busca la *eficiencia* y se necesitan número negativos parece el más adecuado.

Adjunto una verificación de eficiencia que demuestra lo anteriormente comentado.

```
public class Ejemplo 
{

  long tiempo_inicio1, tiempo_inicio2, tiempo_inicio3, tiempo_fin1, tiempo_fin2, tiempo_fin3, total1, total2, total3;
  int numero,contador;

  public Ejemplo()
  {
    numero = 33982332;
    contador = 1000000;
  }   

  public void metodo1()
  {
    int digitos;
    tiempo_inicio1  = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int x = 0; x<contador; x++)
    {
      digitos = Integer.toString(numero).length();
    }

    tiempo_fin1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    total1 = tiempo_fin1 - tiempo_inicio1;
  }

  public void metodo2()
  {
    int digitos;
    tiempo_inicio2  = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int x = 0; x<contador; x++)
    {
      digitos = (int)(Math.log10(numero)+1);
    }

    tiempo_fin2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    total2 = tiempo_fin2 - tiempo_inicio2;
  }

  public void metodo3()
  {
    int digitos = 0;
    tiempo_inicio3  = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int x = 0; x<contador; x++)
    {
      int num = numero;
      while(num !=0)
      {
        num = num/10;
        digitos++;
      }
    } 

    tiempo_fin3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    total3 = tiempo_fin3 - tiempo_inicio3;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {

   Ejemplo ejemplo = new Ejemplo();

   ejemplo.metodo1();
   ejemplo.metodo2();
   ejemplo.metodo3();



   System.out.println("Tiempo empleado con método 1 (Convirtiendo a String) = " + ejemplo.total1);
   System.out.println("Tiempo empleado con método 2 (Usando Math)           = " + ejemplo.total2);
   System.out.println("Tiempo empleado con método 3 (Divisiones entre 10)   = " + ejemplo.total3);   
  }
}
```

La salida sería algo así:

```
$ java Ejemplo 
Tiempo empleado con método 1 (Convirtiendo a String) = 78
Tiempo empleado con método 2 (Usando Math)           = 6 
Tiempo empleado con método 3 (Divisiones entre 10)   = 18
```

Comment: @pero dijo de un numero, no de una cadena

Comment: @rn3w Realmente si lo pasas a cadena y utilizas su propiedad length es lo mismo. Puedes obtener cuantos dígitos tiene obteniendo la largura con la propiedad length.

Comment: @Error404 en eso estoy deacuerdo pero puede que es un trabajo donde estudia, y no es la manera, la mejor manera de hacerlo es descomponiendo el numero

Comment: @rn3w Tampoco veo que haya intentado nada de código. De esta manera, su profesor también puede observar si se esfuerza en su trabajo o si copia las soluciones de internet, lo cual no le va a servir para aprender.

Comment: @Error404 si hubiese hecho de esta manera en mis examenes directamente me ponian cero.

Comment: @rn3w Por eso mismo. Le puedes ayudar, y hay mil maneras de ayudar. Sin embargo, si no veo esfuerzo no creo que tampoco necesiten una recompensa así de fácil.

Comment: Bueno mejoré la respuesta con la contribución de Dev Joel...

Answer (score 2):

Para números positivos o negativos enteros ésta es mi solución usando sólo matemáticas:

```
double numero = -6794;
if(numero == 0) numero++;
System.out.println(Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(numero)) + 1));
```

La salida es:

> 4.0

La explicación desde dentro hacia fuera de la sentencia es:

1. Si es cero le sumo uno para que no me de error
2. Lo paso a volar absoluto por si es negativo
3. Le aplico el logaritmo en base diez para ver la potencia de 10 (son posiciones de dígitos)
4. Redondeo para tomar ya un valor "entero"
5. Le sumo 1 ya que los numeros menores de 10 su potencia es 0
6. Imprimo

Answer (score 1):

Convertirlo a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) mediante el método [valueOf(int valor)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)) para posteriormente acceder a su propiedad Length , mediante el método [length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length())

```
int length = String.valueOf(1000).length()
```

Sin convertirlo a cadena. Sería Realizando divisiones sucesivas de la siguiente forma.

```
while(num !=0) {
   num = num/10;
   cantidad ++;
} 
System.out.println(cantidad);
```

O mediante la fórmula haciendo uso de la clase [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) aplicando el método [log10()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10(double)) . [Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int) *(Teniendo en consideración que no funcionará este método para números negativos)*

```
 int n = 1000;
 int cantidad = (int)(Math.log10(n)+1);
```

Comment: Para completar la respuesta puedes añadir el método convertir a cadena: int length = String.valueOf(1000).length();

Comment: Sí ,lo hice @Webserveis

Comment: Hay veces que existen varias formas de solucionar un problema y cada una de las formas se adapta mejor que otras en función de las circunstancias. No obstante creo que éste no es el caso. Pasar a String y usar su método length() es lo aconsejable en todos los casos, pues ayuda a mantener el código claro. Las otras dos soluciones parece que pretenden ofuscar el código sin añadir ningún tipo de mejora perceptible. Otra cosa bien distinta sería que estuviéramos utilizando otro lenguaje de programación que careciera del método length(), pero no es el caso. Es una opinión claro está ;-)

Comment: Usted lo ah dicho. varias formas por eso expongo tres en mi respuesta. **código claro no significa siempre el más eficiente** claro para averiguar de un número no se notará la diferencia, pero para una cantidad mayor si será. creo que el de divisiones sucesivas es más eficiente.

Comment: Pues si Dev. Joel. La verdad es que tienes razón, estuve haciendo pruebas y hay considerables diferencias de rendimiento en situaciones de cálculos muy intensivos... así que completo la respuesta X-D. Gracias. El primer método no es el aconsejable en todos los casos.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int digitos(int numero){
      String a=numero+"";
      a=a.replace(".","");
      a=a.replace("-","");
    return a.length();
}
```

Con este método ya no tomarías en cuenta los puntos ni el signo negativo.

Answer (score 1):

en java:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
    int num=0;
    int aumento=10;
    int div=1;
    int numeros[]=null;
    do {            
     System.out.println("Ingresa un numero: (numero mayor que cero y menor de 7 digitos)");
     num=teclado.nextInt();         
    } while (num<1 || num>999999);

    String num2=String.valueOf(num);
    numeros=new int[num2.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < num2.length() ; i++) {

        numeros[i]=num%aumento/div;
        aumento=aumento*10;
        div=div*10;
    }
   for (int i = numeros.length-1; i >=0; i--) {            
    System.out.println(""+numeros[i]);
    }
}
```